# Customize Navigationview menu UI Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am using NavigationView control of android to create sliding drawer.
All is fine except spacing between Menu Items in navigation view as shown in image.

Thank you in advance guys[image]

**Navigationview**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/homescreen_header"
    app:menu="@menu/homescreen_nav_drawer"

    app:itemIconTint="@color/green"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/White"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationView"
    app:itemBackground="@color/nav_item_bg"
    android:background="@color/nav_item_bg"
    />

<style name="NavigationView" >
    <item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: I think I need to do something in theme.But missing exactness

Comment: @ Ironman
I tried out both solutions,  but wont working

Comment: @JayVyas in your `dimen` add this one `<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">0dp</dimen>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a style with

```
   <style name="NavigationViewStyle">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">25dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
</style>
```

and apply this style to NavigationView

```
 app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
```